# unfolding a developable surface

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a developable $S$ surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by the two space curves $f(t)$ and $g(t)$. For any $t \in [0;1]$ a straight line connects the two point $f(t)$ and $g(t)$. These lines lie within and defines $S$.

Since every point on $S$ thus lies on a straight line, the Gaussian curvature is $0$ and therefore $S$ is developable.

I'd like to "unfold" the surface. I.e. find the plane curves $f'(t)$ and $g'(t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that similarly defines the unfolded surface.

Example: if $S$ is a cylinder with height $h$ and radius $r$, the unfolded surface would be a rectangle with height $h$ and length $2\pi r$.

Obviously, there would be at least one infinity of solutions, since any orientation of the unfolded surface would be a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is far from being solvable with closed formulae. Since geodesic curvature is preserved under isometry, the "unfolding" you are looking for would send the curve parametrized by $f(t)$ to a plane curve whose curvature matches the geodesic curvature (with respect to the surface in issue) of the space curve.

A bit more practically, once you know the geodesic curvature of your space curve, there is just one plane curve, up to rigid motions, having exactly that same curvature with respect to the same parametrization. You can read about this for example in *do Carmo*'s "Differential geometry of curves and surfaces" . Finding the curve explicitly is in general hard. Numerics can be used to get an idea of how the curve looks like, though.

In your example, the two boundary curves you consider are geodesics (geodesic curvature is $0$) therefore their developement must be a plane curve whose curvature is constantly $0$: the edge of your rectangle, a line segment.